# How can I validate my input only if my field is not disabled

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, disabled-input, ng-required

How can I validate my input only if my field is not disabled. I would like to write something like `ng-required="job_name.disabled!="disabled""` but I'm not getting it right.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.job.name" name="job_name" 
       validate-on="dirty" ng-disabled="true" ng-required="true" 
       required-message="'Name is required!'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.job.name" name="job_name" validate-on="dirty" ng-disabled="vm.disabled" ng-required="!vm.disabled" required-message="'Name is required!'" />
```

It means require if not disabled, and keep disable condition on your scope. In the short form

```
<input ng-disabled="vm.disabled" ng-required="!vm.disabled" />
```